# Frequency Counter in array of objects for certain key

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with students name which are getting repeated often. I want to create a frequency counter of the students name with the number of total counts.

Array :

```
arr = [
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        age: '15',
    },
    {
        name: 'Rajat',
        age: '14',
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        age: '16',
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: '12',
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        age: '11',
    },
    {
        name: 'Rajat',
        age: '17',
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        age: '12',
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: '18',
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: '19',
    }
    
]
```

I want to get the result like this in an array

```
result = [
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        count: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'Rajat',
        count: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Sam',
        count: 3
    },
]
```

I tried the below solution but it's not working properly -

```
const result = arr.reduce((counter,item) => {
    var getItem = item.name;
    counter[getItem] = counter.hasOwnProperty(getItem) ? counter[getItem] : 1;
    return counter;
})
```

Please help.

Comment: You should use `reduce` with an initial value, an empty object. And you should increment the previous value.

Comment: Your `reduce` call is missing the initial value (use `{}`), and you need to convert the result to the array that you're looking for. Apart from those the approach is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an accumulator in the reduce. In this case pass an empty object as an accumulator , so the accumulator will look like

```
{
 name:{
  name:someName,
  count:someCount
 },
 name2:{
  name:someName,
  count:someCount
  }
}
```

Once the accumulator is successfully populated, then use Object.values to get an array

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Akshay',
    age: '15',
  },
  {
    name: 'Rajat',
    age: '14',
  },
  {
    name: 'Akshay',
    age: '16',
  },
  {
    name: 'Sam',
    age: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'Akshay',
    age: '11',
  },
  {
    name: 'Rajat',
    age: '17',
  },
  {
    name: 'Akshay',
    age: '12',
  },
  {
    name: 'Sam',
    age: '18',
  },
  {
    name: 'Sam',
    age: '19',
  }

]

const result = arr.reduce((counter, item) => {
  var getItem = item.name;
  if (counter.hasOwnProperty(getItem)) {
    counter[getItem].count += 1;
  } else {
    counter[getItem] = {
      name: getItem,
      count: 1
    };

  }
  return counter;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (you have been missing the initial value)

```
const count = arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  prev[cur.name] = (prev[cur.name] || 0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```